# How to deal with params in URL schema in Django application

Tags: python, django, http, url

As we know most URL schemes base their URL syntax on this nine-part general format: 
`<scheme>://<user>:<password>@<host>:<port>/<path>;<params>?<query>#<frag>`

I know I can get the query strings in Django request.GET dict. But how to get parameters? It seems HttpRequest in Django can not deal with params defined in URL.

For example: http://www.example.com/hello;param1=aaaa;param2=bbbb

Is there any way to extract params like this in Django without writing own regex in url pattern.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If I understood your question properly,
you will have to write a regex to extract params from the URL. Is that what you want?

Comment: @VishalSh Thank you for your reply. I want to know if Django can extract the params by itself. If it can't, I have to use query strings. There is no need to write regex by myself, not worth it.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that a semi-colon delimited params segment is part of the standard URL scheme? I've never seen such a thing, and it's not a part of the relevant [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path segment parameters you're talking about were defined in [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396#section-3.3). This RFC has been obsolete since 2005. The new standard, RFC 3986, does not define a specific way to define path segment parameters. The relevant section [states](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3):

> Aside from dot-segments in hierarchical paths, a path segment is
> considered opaque by the generic syntax. [...] For
> example, the semicolon (";") and equals ("=") reserved characters are
> often used to delimit parameters and parameter values applicable to
> that segment.  [...]  Parameter types may be defined by scheme-specific
> semantics, but in most cases the syntax of a parameter is specific to
> the implementation of the URI's dereferencing algorithm.

Django uses the new standard and does not define any specific way to parse path segment parameters. However, Python defines the `urlparse()` function, which parses the url according to RFC2396. You can use this to extract the path parameters:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse  # urlparse.urlparse on Python 2

params = urlparse(request.path).params
```

Comment: `urlparse()` only parses out path parameters from the *last segment* of the path; there is currently no code in the standard library to parse out such parameters elsewhere in the path.

Answer (score 0):

to capture params you've to define url patterns as per that.

lets assume your url is *http://myurl.com/mydashboard/250?sort=-1&q=this* so here 250 is param which you want.

To capture the same you've to define url like below

```
url(r'^mydashboard/(?P<weeknum>\d+)/$',
    mydashboard, name='mydashboard'),
```

and now the view definition of mydashboard will have another input param like below

```
def nagdashboard(request, weeknum):
```

And to get GET params or POST params you can use.

```
request.GET.get('sort')
```

For further reading on patterns refer to [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#patterns)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Maybe my description is not so clear. For example there is a url like: http://www.example.com/hello;param1=aaa;param2=bbb and I want to know if Django can deal with param defined like this.

Comment: in that case I think django will work correctly. For this case the pattern will be like ^hello;param1=(?P<param1>\w+);param2=(?P<param2>\w+)$ and view will be like def myhelloview(request, param1, param2). I havent tested it though but I faced similar issue few months back and regex worked like a charm.. :) Hope it helps you..

Comment: I think it is not so perfect for using regex in url pattern. The combination of param's order or param's amount can be complex. The params may even be optional. ;-)

Comment: okay got your point.. In that case everything after hello can be treated as a single argument and later you can create a default dict and then isolate the values..